# Changing margin between section number and section title

Tags: koma-script, section-titles

How can I change my title from this

[image: Wrong]

to that?
[image: Right]

My code:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc,ngerman,11pt,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[a4paper,inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=3.205556cm,bottom=2cm,headsep=0.705556cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%Schriftgröße Section
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{13pt}{13.8pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{11pt}{13.8pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\paragraphfont{\fontsize{13pt}{12pt}\sffamily\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\section[Kurz Titel]{Formatvorlage: “Überschrift 1” Überschrift des Hauptberichtes Überschrift des Hauptberichtes (Kapitelnummer anpassen = Arbeitspunktnummer!)}\label{chap:Zusammenfassung}

\begin{addmargin}[1cm]{0cm}
\paragraph{\textbf{\textit{Englischer Titel (Formatvorlage “Englischer Titel”), Englischer Titel (Formatvorlage “Englischer Titel”) Einzug 1 cm links
}}}\mbox{}\\
\end{addmargin}

\noindent\hspace*{1cm} 
X.-ing. Vorname Nachname (Formatvorlage "Titel und Name") Einzug 1 cm Links

\textit{
\paragraph{Summary Formatvorlage: “Überschrift Summary” (ca. 1,5 Seiten)}\mbox{}\\[12pt]
\normalsize
„Formatvorlage Standard Summary“.
\blindtext}

\paragraph{Zusammenfassung Formatvorlage: “Überschrift Zusammenfassung” (ca. 1,5 Seiten)}\mbox{}\\[12pt]
„Formatvorlage: Standard“. 
\normalsize
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, twoside, usegeometry=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterskip=12pt,
font=\sffamily\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont\bfseries\RaggedRight
]{section}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
\makebox[1.5cm][l]{\thesection\autodot\enskip}}

\newenvironment{englsect}{%
  \begin{addmargin}[1.5cm]{0pt}%
    \sffamily\itshape\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont%
    \selectlanguage{english}}
  {\end{addmargin}\selectlanguage{ngerman}\bigskip}

\newenvironment{whowroteit}{%
  \begin{addmargin}[1.5cm]{0pt}%
    \sffamily\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont%
    \selectlanguage{english}}
  {\end{addmargin}\selectlanguage{ngerman}\par}


\begin{document}
\section{Überschriftentest -- unusual and very long heading as a test for getting a
  second line}
\label{sec:uberschriftentest}
\begin{englsect}
  And now the very long english title which also is somewhat longish and so on and
  on. 
\end{englsect}

\begin{whowroteit}
  X.-Ing. Vorname Name and whatever
\end{whowroteit}


\end{document}
```

[image: pic of pdf]